# How to specify the week number for a given date using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe using

```
year_start = '2020-03-29'

year_end = '2021-04-10'

week_end_sat = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(year_start, year_end, freq=f'W-SAT'), columns=['a'])
```

How can I make another column specifying the week number making 2020-03-29 as the first day of the calendar since I am trying to make a 4-4-5 calendar which always ends on a Saturday?

Final df that I want is,

```
     a     |  count
2020-04-04 |    1
2020-04-11 |    2
.
.
.
2021-04-03 |    53   #since 2020 is a leap year there are 53 weeks otherwise it will be 52 weeks
2021-04-10 |    1
2021-04-17 |    2
.
2022-03-02 |    52
2022-04-09 |    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create a baseline date range start from the first day of your given `year_start`.

```py
first_day_of_year = week_end_sat.iloc[0, 0].replace(day=1, month=1)
baseline = pd.Series(pd.date_range(first_day_of_year, periods=len(week_end_sat), freq=f'W-SAT'))
```

The baseline's week of year is what you want.

```py
week_end_sat['count'] = baseline['a'].dt.isocalendar().week
```

```py
# print(week_end_sat)

            a  count
0  2020-04-04     1
1  2020-04-11     2
2  2020-04-18     3
3  2020-04-25     4
4  2020-05-02     5
5  2020-05-09     6
6  2020-05-16     7
7  2020-05-23     8
8  2020-05-30     9
9  2020-06-06    10
10 2020-06-13    11
11 2020-06-20    12
12 2020-06-27    13
13 2020-07-04    14
14 2020-07-11    15
15 2020-07-18    16
16 2020-07-25    17
17 2020-08-01    18
18 2020-08-08    19
19 2020-08-15    20
20 2020-08-22    21
21 2020-08-29    22
...
43 2021-01-30    44
44 2021-02-06    45
45 2021-02-13    46
46 2021-02-20    47
47 2021-02-27    48
48 2021-03-06    49
49 2021-03-13    50
50 2021-03-20    51
51 2021-03-27    52
52 2021-04-03    53
53 2021-04-10     1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking out time and solving my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I calculated the week number using a W-Sat frequency and isocalendar api and return the week number.  I then create a baseline using the first day of the year and assign the week number to baseline_week.  Now the week has an associated baseline_week number.

```
 year_start = '2020-03-29'
 year_end = '2021-04-10'

 df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(year_start, year_end, freq=f'W-SAT'),      columns=['week_date'])
 df['week_number']=df['week_date'].apply(lambda row: datetime.date(row.year, row.month, row.day).isocalendar()[1])

 first_day_of_year = df.iloc[0, 0].replace(day=1, month=1)
 baseline = pd.Series(pd.date_range(first_day_of_year, periods=len(df), freq=f'W-SAT'))

 df['baseline_date']=baseline
 df['baseline_week_number']=df['baseline_date'].apply(lambda row: datetime.date(row.year, row.month, row.day).isocalendar()[1])
 print(df)
```

output:

```
 week_date  week_number baseline_date  baseline_week_number
 0  2020-04-04           14    2020-01-04                     1
 1  2020-04-11           15    2020-01-11                     2
 2  2020-04-18           16    2020-01-18                     3
 3  2020-04-25           17    2020-01-25                     4
 4  2020-05-02           18    2020-02-01                     5
 5  2020-05-09           19    2020-02-08                     6
 6  2020-05-16           20    2020-02-15                     7
 7  2020-05-23           21    2020-02-22                     8
 8  2020-05-30           22    2020-02-29                     9
 9  2020-06-06           23    2020-03-07                    10
 10 2020-06-13           24    2020-03-14                    11
 11 2020-06-20           25    2020-03-21                    12
 12 2020-06-27           26    2020-03-28                    13
 13 2020-07-04           27    2020-04-04                    14
 14 2020-07-11           28    2020-04-11                    15
 15 2020-07-18           29    2020-04-18                    16
 16 2020-07-25           30    2020-04-25                    17
 17 2020-08-01           31    2020-05-02                    18
 18 2020-08-08           32    2020-05-09                    19
 19 2020-08-15           33    2020-05-16                    20
 20 2020-08-22           34    2020-05-23                    21
 21 2020-08-29           35    2020-05-30                    22
 22 2020-09-05           36    2020-06-06                    23
 23 2020-09-12           37    2020-06-13                    24
 24 2020-09-19           38    2020-06-20                    25
 25 2020-09-26           39    2020-06-27                    26
 26 2020-10-03           40    2020-07-04                    27
 27 2020-10-10           41    2020-07-11                    28
 28 2020-10-17           42    2020-07-18                    29
 29 2020-10-24           43    2020-07-25                    30
 30 2020-10-31           44    2020-08-01                    31
 31 2020-11-07           45    2020-08-08                    32
 32 2020-11-14           46    2020-08-15                    33
 33 2020-11-21           47    2020-08-22                    34
 34 2020-11-28           48    2020-08-29                    35
 35 2020-12-05           49    2020-09-05                    36
 36 2020-12-12           50    2020-09-12                    37
 37 2020-12-19           51    2020-09-19                    38
 38 2020-12-26           52    2020-09-26                    39
 39 2021-01-02           53    2020-10-03                    40
 40 2021-01-09            1    2020-10-10                    41
 41 2021-01-16            2    2020-10-17                    42
 42 2021-01-23            3    2020-10-24                    43
 43 2021-01-30            4    2020-10-31                    44
 44 2021-02-06            5    2020-11-07                    45
 45 2021-02-13            6    2020-11-14                    46
 46 2021-02-20            7    2020-11-21                    47
 47 2021-02-27            8    2020-11-28                    48
 48 2021-03-06            9    2020-12-05                    49
 49 2021-03-13           10    2020-12-12                    50
 50 2021-03-20           11    2020-12-19                    51
 51 2021-03-27           12    2020-12-26                    52
 52 2021-04-03           13    2021-01-02                    53
 53 2021-04-10           14    2021-01-09                     1
```